# having trouble with authinfo proxy settings for emacs

Tags: emacs, proxy, elpa

I just started using emacs and I am trying to install the package.el and it has trouble with the proxy. When I try to run the commands from [elpa install site](http://tromey.com/elpa/install.html) the "url-retrieve-synchronously" command returns a buffer with a 407 error (I know this because I wrote the what it returns to a file and saw it, if use a www.google.com, which doesn't require a proxy, it returns the page).

I think the problem is with the username for the proxy. It has the form:

> STUDENTS\123454

I think it is the "\" character thats giving trouble. I tried doing

> STUDENTS\123457  |   "STUDENTS\1233467" | "STUDENTS\\1234567"

and it does not work.

My ~./authinfo file looks like this has this

> machine proxys.vasity.ac.za:80 port http login STUDENTS\12234 password 012TTjal

I am running emacs23 from the Ubuntu Natty repos. I have no other configurations that I am aware of for emacs.

I have my bash http_proxy set and wget works. So my questions are :

- is there a way to tell the url.el package that emacs comes with to use wget instead of what its using now?
- can I specify my username so that url.el works?
- is the username the issue or have I missed a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

`package.el` is now part of vanilla Emacs. Consider filing an Emacs bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Also, there are now a few variants of `package.el` out there, and it seems to evolve fairly quickly as well.  If you use Tom Tromey's version of the file, consider contacting him directly about the problem.